# Javascript: Event for when video src is loaded?

Tags: javascript

Is there an event listener for when a video's src is loaded?

I've noticed sometimes YouTube takes a few seconds to load the video src on Safari Mobile on iPhone. Ideally there is a callback on HTMLVideoElement.prototype for when src is loaded.

I've tried this [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_loadeddata.asp)

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.onloadeddata = function() {
    alert("Browser has loaded the current frame");
};
```

but with no luck.

Comment: Did you try `canplay`? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/canplay

Comment: I think that works! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an event called **oncanplay**, which is triggered when the src of the video was loaded. try this code :

```
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
video.oncanplay = function() {
    alert("Start watching video");
};
```